# oracle stored procedure using date parameter

Tags: oracle, plsql

Is it possible to use a date parameter for a stored procedure?
for example, date 20171201 I need to execute a case A in a dateparameter.prc 
and date 20171202 execute a case B in a dateparameter.prc which is the same procedure above.
I am googling and investigating some books but I still haven't found a solution.
Can anyone know about it?
Thanks

Comment: So, the question is "Is it possible?" and the answer is "Yes, it is possible."

Comment: You can pass parameters of any type. `DATE` is a standard, built-in type, just like `NUMBER` or `VARCHAR2`. What isn't working?

Comment: Thanks, I am a newbie so I don't know much about oracle yet.
have a good day~!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

```
SQL> set serveroutput on

SQL> create procedure dt_demo(p_d date) as
  2  begin
  3    dbms_output.put_line('p_d = ' || p_d);
  4  end;
  5  /

Procedure created

SQL> exec dt_demo(date '2017-12-02');

p_d = 02.12.17

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment
I am doing coding now!

Answer (score 1):

Your procedure is functioning correctly. But

1. The expression "DATE '2017-12-02'" represents the ISO date standard.
2. The expression "dbms_output.put_line('p_d = ' || p_d)" represents the regular Oracle date processing, which precedes the ISO specification.

How the date is formatted (displayed) during dbms_ouput converts the date to a string. Since in this case there is an implicit conversion the resulting format is controlled by the NLS_DATA_FORMAT setting. It looks like yours is set to "dd-mm-yy". To see the difference insert/run the following before your exec statement:

`alter session set nls_date_format = 'yyyy-mm-dd`" ;

Also see Oracle [Date Format](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00210) for Oracle 11g or as appropriate for your version.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to use a date parameter for a stored procedure?

Yes. A simple example that takes a date as an `IN` date parameter and passes it directly to an `OUT` date parameter is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE your_procedure(
  in_value   IN  DATE,
  out_return OUT DATE
)
IS
BEGIN
  out_return := in_value;
END;
/
```